# Auto logout after an hour of inactivity (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am making a new web interface for a legacy database. It's a system within a local web. Each user has their own credentials for the database connection (a single URL, but many users). In addition, users should be able to use a single account from multiple computers simultaneously.

I made a form with username and password. I created CustomAuthenticationProvider, so when a person logs in, it creates new Connection for that person and puts it into my ConnectionPool.
Now I need some solution for closing connections for inactive users who haven't made any requests for an hour and logging them out.
Any help and criticism are welcome.

CustomAuthenticationProvider

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    ConnectionPool connectionPool;

    @Autowired
    AccountLoader accountLoader;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String id = authentication.getName();
        List<Object> account = accountLoader.findUserById(id);

        String username = (String) account.get(0);
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        try {
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(1);
            connectionPool.addConnection(id, username, password);
            CustomPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal(id, username, (String) account.get(1));
            principal.setLastActivity(new Date());
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, null);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid password", e);
        } finally {
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

}
```

ConnectionPool

```
@Service
public class ConnectionPool {

    @Value("${dao.url}")
    private String url;

    private final Map<String, Connection> pool = new HashMap<>();

    public Connection addConnection(String id, String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        pool.put(id, connection);
        return connection;
    }

    public Connection getConnection(String id) {
        return pool.get(id);
    }

    public void closeConnection(String id) throws SQLException {
        pool.get(id).close();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void closeAll() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("Closing all connections");
        for (Connection connection : pool.values()) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }

}
```

FilterChainConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class FilterChainConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new CustomSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    CustomFailureHandler failureHandler() {
        return new CustomFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth
                                .requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/css/**", "/image/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(configurer ->
                        configurer
                                .loginPage("/auth/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login")
                                .successHandler(successHandler())
                                .failureHandler(failureHandler())
                                .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(configurer ->
                        configurer
                                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                                .clearAuthentication(true)
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/logout"))
                                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login")
                                .permitAll()
                )
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager())
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```